# Make single legend for two subplots of DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I create a plot with two axes on different subplots. Currently one overlays another. The problem is to make legend to contain both labels in stack. How can I do this?

```
d = data.groupby('atemp_rounded').sum().reset_index()
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111) # don't know what 111 stands for...
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
d.plot(ax=ax1, y='casual')
d.plot(ax=ax2, y='registered', color='g')
plt.show()
```

[image: bad legend]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may set the legend of the individual plots off and instead create a figure legend. To have this placed within the axes boundaries the position needs to be specified in axes coordinates.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A" : [3,2,1], "B" : [2,2,1]})

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111) # don't know what 111 stands for...
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
df.plot(ax=ax1, y='A', legend=False)
df.plot(ax=ax2, y='B', color='g', legend=False)
fig.legend(loc="upper right", bbox_to_anchor=(0,0,1,1), bbox_transform=ax1.transAxes)
plt.show()
```

[image]